# client certificates in .NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, client, certificate

can anyone explain to me the difference between client certificates and the public certificates we see in SSL?

why do we need a private key in client certificates?

i currently have a client certificate that does not have a private key associated with it and IIS keeps asking for a private key.

please help!

Comment: I would suggest you to read a little bit about how digital certificates work before jumping into implementations.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123848%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can update your own question by editing it. You can vote for questions (upvote or downvote) and if you get the answer that satisfies your needs and answers your question, you can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Client certificate is used (as its name suggests) to authenticate the client to the server during SSL/TLS handshake. In order for any certificate to be used for authentication, the authenticating party must have a private key, which is a proof of authenticity (in other words, the one who owns the private key owns the title). Consequently, if you use some certificate to authenticate a client, you must have a corresponding private key. The private key never leaves client side, it's only used in certain cryptographic implementations.

However, your question is confusing. On the server you usually authenticate the server to the client, and you use server's certificate for this. You can tell the server, that certain client's certificate is trusted and the client can authenticate itself using this certificate, but you don't need client's private key for this. So you are doing something wrong with IIS.

Comment: Hi Eugene, now i have a server certificate that i've imported into the server's keystore.

how then do i generate the client certificate ?

Comment: @user693425 The question is too broad. Please learn the basics of PKI by reading some book - this will give you both understanding of concepts and also much more general-purpose information that you would obtain from SO. SO is a technical site for practical questions where one is expected to know the theory.

Comment: have updated the question to be more technically detailed.
will read up more on the theory part...

thnaks

Comment: @user693425 I've performed rollback of your editions because new question is completely different from previous one. You can submit your technical question as a new question instead (click on "edited ... ago by Eugene Mayevski" to get to the history and take your edition from there and copy them to the new question).

Answer (score 1):

> I currently have a client certificate
>   that does not have a private key
>   associated with it

This is a contradiction in terms. Every certificate has a private key associated with it. It is installed at the client along with the certificate. It was generated prior the certificate in fact. The certificate itself can be exported, but this is without the private key. This is done e.g. to get the server to trust the client if the client certificate isn't signed by someone the server already trusts.

Comment: hi EJP, public key certificates do not contain private keys.
in normal SSL handshake the public keys in the certificate will be used to encrypt the data which the server's private key can decrypt.

now my confusion is..is the client certificate a public key certificate then?

Comment: user693425: (1) Certificates don't contain private keys. I didn't state otherwise; (2) asymmetric encryption only occurs in the SSL handshake in certain cipher suites, not the 'normal SSL handshake'; (3) all PKI certificates are 'public key certificates'.

Comment: currently i have both .cer and .pfx certificates.
i install the pfx certificate in the server side.
and my client application uses the .cer certificate to establish the connection.


however, from my asp.net application i keep getting this error:


**Cannot find the certificate in either the LocalMachine store or the CurrentUser store.**


**i already have the certificate imported into the windows keystore and permissions granted to "NETWORK SERVICE".**


any idea?

Answer (score 0):

A certificate contains a public key of a key pair. Somebody holds the private key of the key pair, and keeps that secret. It is stored separate from the certificate, unless you bundle them together to transport them, in a PFX file, for example.

When the server has a "server certificate", that's a certificate with a public key in it, and the server also has the private key kept safely somewhere. It uses the private key to sign something on the SSL handshake. The client only needs the server certificate, which only has the public key of the server's key pair, to verify that signature, to determine that the server does in fact hold the private key of the server key pair.

When the client sends a "client certificate" on the SSL connection for client authentication, then the client will have it's own private key kept safely on its side. It's possible to neglect to import the private key when you import a client certificate on the client machine, when the certificate was generated somewhere else. But the client will need to have that client private key in order to sign something in the SSL handshake, to prove to the server that it holds the private key of the client key pair.

The server only sees the client certificate, which only has the public key. The public key, along with the something that the client has signed, proves that the client holds the private key. Neither side sends its own private key to the other side. They only send the certificates, which only carry the public key along with the certificate stuff (common name, issuer, etc.)